# ios App Development inactive

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to create certificate for my iphone application but in `developer.apple.com -> Certificate -> Development` **ios App Development** part is **inactive**, so i can't choose it. But my application must receive remote push notification. So, Which one should I choose ? : `Ios App Development` or `Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox)`.

I choose `Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox)` but I could not get ant push message.

> - Why Ios App Development is inactive ?
> - What can I do?

Simple my application should receive remote push notification messages.

Answer (score 1):

**First thing** you need to do Most Importantly :

- Go through [Apple's Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW1) (Everything is given there). It will give you the Fundamental Knowledge about each and every aspects of Push Notifications.

**Second thing :**

- You can take a look at [Ray Wenderlich's Beautiful Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) about Push Notification.